# GitHub Labels for ORG not showing in repos

Tags: github

I have read this doc: https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-default-labels-for-repositories-in-your-organization

Based on this, custom labels will only be applied to new repos

> Default labels are included in every new repository in your organization, but anyone with write access to the repository can edit or delete the labels in that repository later. Adding, editing, or deleting a default label does not add, edit, or delete the label from existing repositories.

Which I have tested and all good there.

The question: Is there a way to add new `Labels` to the ORG and load them in all repos.

- No manual adding(tested, of course works but not worth it)

Thanks, @T04435

Answer (score 1):

We don't find any way to sync the newly organization labels to existing repos.
According to this [document](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_label_clone), `gh clone label` command works well for my project, but it is still manual work on repository level.